# Inserting a new paragraph between two existing tables

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In a TinyMce textarea, I have a content where several tables directly follow each other (there's no content between the tables themselves). Using TinyMce, I want to allow my users to insert a new paragraph between those tables... but that doesn't seem possible?... (Not sure whether I'm missing something or if it's an oversight.)

If I try to click between the tables (even if they have a CSS margin applied), the cursor goes immediately inside the closest cell of one of the tables. Same thing if I move the cursor with the keyboard arrow keys: it jumps from table 1 to table 2 without stopping between them. So there's no way to add a new element between those tables.

I sometimes work with ckEditor on Drupal projects, and it has a sort of red horizontal line that appears on hover, when you move your mouse between block-level elements. Clicking on this red line allows to insert a new paragraph between those blocks. Is there some equivalent for TinyMCE? (Or another solution?)

Answer (score 1):

Use your mouse to target the end of the table and then hit enter. In this fiddle I created http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Vygaab/1 I add one table, add a second table, then use my mouse target the end of the first table.

Note that neither table should be selected, and when you target the end of the first table, it shouldn't show as selected.

Then if you hit enter, you should get a new paragraph. In this fast example, I took the borders off the table so you can see the cursor blinking more easily.

This was built with the latest Cloud Stable version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's interesting (I didn't know that) but if you test a bit more, you'll see that it doesn't really work. First you have to make sure no table is selected (the cursor is not in any of them) by clicking outside of them. This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. But even in Chrome, it's very limited. Try adding 4 tables. You can add a paragraph between table 3 and 4 like you say. Now try adding a paragraph between tables 1 and 2: impossible, the paragraph is still added between tables 3 and 4. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Last test: try adding 2 tables, then one paragraph after them (but still nothing between them). Now try adding a paragraph between the 2 tables: impossible, it's added where the paragraph already is. In other word, it seems this solution will add a paragraph between tables *only if* there's no other paragraph before or after the tables already. This leaves a lot of situations where it's impossible to add a paragraph between tables. (I'm wondering whether it's a real feature or just an unintended side effect.)